# Post form field values on event change to ActionResult

Tags: jquery-post

I have a MVC view that has many fields, input, checkboxes, select lists etc. 
When the user makes a choice in any field I use jQuery to trigger a change event that picks the values in all fields and make a (ajax) post to a ActionResult method (with all the values) which makes a database query and at last a search result is returned.
The values from the html fields are put back into the fields so that the user may continue narrowing down his search.

I find it very error-prone and cumbersome to use JQuery for this. I have taken a look at Angular and React, but these seems bloated if I only need it for above task.

I'm open towards frameworks, nuget packages, programming languages, as long as it fits well with above explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite feel right as an approach- if you are posting to .NET with AJAX, why not post to a WEBAPI controller, and get back a Json results set - deal with everything in JavaScript (jQuery). However, I'd still keep the form element wrapper and use that to post to the ActionResult MVC controller method to return a View for no-JS scenarios.

Comment: Hi Andiih, the ActionResult is also returning a json object, hence webapi do dont provide any advantage. Furthermore I want to be able to do caching which webapi dont provide. The error-prone and cumbersome part is to use jQuery to pick out all values from all fields and them them along to actionresult method and then when search result is returned  continue using jquery to pick all values out from the json object and place them in corresponding html fields. There got to be a better and less error prone way.